# How to store array element in an array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to store an array to element. So i used 2-D array, but seems it is not working. In this case i am getting 5 IEEE address which is array of 8 bytes. I want to store one by one according to which address in coming first

```
char a[5][8];
int i = 0;
if(data)
{
  a[i] = es->ieee;
  i++;
}
```

//it will receive 5 different address

I need to compare those IEEE address with already store IEEE address,for example there are 5 IEEE address

```
char First[8] = "0x32441";
char Second[8] = "0x42421";

if(a[1] == First)
{
  printf("it is matching in First");
}
```

Can any one help me out

Comment: Please consider reading some C tutorial material, or even a good book. There seems to be pretty large gaps in your knowledge, at the moment. :|

Answer (score 1):

Let's call these "strings", since that seems to be how you think of them, despite that you say otherwise.

In C, a string is an array of `char` that ends with a `char` whose value is 0.

Strings are "assigned" (copied) with `strcpy()`, since you cannot directly assign an entire array, usually.

This would mean that your initial example probably should be something like:

```
if(data)
  strcpy(a[i++], es->ieee);
```

it's hard to be sure, since you don't tell us what `es` is.

Also, strings are compared with the `strcmp()` function, you cannot use `==` to compare strings directly (since they are arrays, and arrays cannot be compared with `==` either).

This means that the second snippet should be:

```
if(strcmp(a[1], First) == 0)
  printf("it is matching First\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

C does not have array assignment. You need to use [`memcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) (or possibly `strncmp`, this seems one of the *rare* cases where it is actually appropriate function):

```
char a[5][8];
int i = 0;
if(data)
{
  memcpy(a[i], es->ieee, 8);
  i++;
}
```

And C does not support comparing arrays with operators either, so use [`memcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcmp) function (or possibly `strncmp`, depending if you have null terminated strings or not):

```
char First[8] = "0x32441";
char Second[8] = "0x42421";

if(memcmp(a[1], First, 8) == 0)
{
  printf("it is matching in First");
}
```